# @media print How to show only child elment within table

Tags: css, html-table

I want to set up a Print page. I use @media print. Now I have the situation that I only want to extract the text out of a table. The simplified table looks like the following:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <p>
          Firstname
        </p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <p>
          Firstname
        </p>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
      <div>
        <p>
          Werner
        </p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <p>
          Horst
        </p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <p>
         50
        </p>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the print page I only want to output the `<p></p>` elements of the whole table but not the rest.

How can I make parent elements invisible while keeping a child element visible?

Hope you can help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could apply `display: inline;` to all used tags except `p`:

```css
table, tr, td, div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <p>
          Firstname
        </p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <p>
          Firstname
        </p>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
      <div>
        <p>
          Werner
        </p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <p>
          Horst
        </p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <p>
         50
        </p>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You might also turn the logic around using  `:not()`:

```
*:not(p, html, body) {
  display: inline;
}
```

(I didn't apply that to your example, since apparently it causes some unexpected resuts here in the snippt)

Comment: Hi, ok for this simple solution it works how a about a more complex. 
https://jsfiddle.net/v8d1znu6/6/